# add control to Panel and control doesn't display anymore c#

Tags: c#

I have one textbox (textBox1) and panel (Panel1) I have code like this

```
Panel1.Controls.Add(textBox1)
```

so when I run it I can't see textbox anymore, If I do like this I can see textBox

```
textBox1.Location  = Panel1.Location
```

can anyone tell me what's problem?

Comment: You have to locate the `textBox1` in the `Panel1`. If you set `textBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0)` then you will see the textbox in the left-top corner of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

When a textbox (or any control) is part of a panel the top left of the panel is point(0.0);

so when textBox1.Location  = Panel1.Location the textbox probably falls out of view in the panel.

try something like this instead/

```
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(59, 27);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(193, 176);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're not able to see the Textbox has to do with the Panel's properties. Try setting the AutoSize property to `true` and the AutoSizeMode property to `GrowAndShrink`.